# split this query

Tags: sql

```
    $sql= "
SELECT tbl_doctors. * , 
       tbl_specialisation. * , 
       tbl_doctor_address.addr_id, 
       tbl_address .  * 
FROM `tbl_doctors` INNER JOIN
     `tbl_specialisation`
     ON ( tbl_doctors.dr_spec_id = tbl_specialisation.spec_id ) INNER JOIN
     (tbl_doctor_address JOIN
      tbl_address
      ON tbl_doctor_address.addr_id = tbl_address.addr_id
     )
     ON tbl_doctors.dr_id = tbl_doctor_address.dr_id  
WHERE tbl_doctors.dr_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Split the query into what?

Comment: If you want a proper help, please ask a proper question.

Comment: Unknown column 'dr_id' in 'where clause' show the error

Comment: You dont get much worse than this question. 1) A command instead of a question.2) Code  only, no description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this part needs to be remodeled:

```
(tbl_doctor_address JOIN
  tbl_address
  ON tbl_doctor_address.addr_id = tbl_address.addr_id
 )
 ON tbl_doctors.dr_id = tbl_doctor_address.dr_id
```

Into like this:

```
INNER JOIN `tbl_doctor_address` ON tbl_doctors.dr_id = tbl_doctor_address.dr_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_address` ON tbl_doctor_address.addr_id = tbl_address.addr_id
```

Or you can use a `LEFT JOIN` if there mustn't be an address set for a doctor:

```
LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctor_address` ON tbl_doctors.dr_id = tbl_doctor_address.dr_id
LEFT JOIN `tbl_address` ON tbl_doctor_address.addr_id = tbl_address.addr_id
```

tell me whether it helps or not?